# Saving a LocalTime in MySql TIME column

Tags: java, mysql, java-time, localtime

### Backstory

I recently came across a problem with saving a `LocalTime` to a `TIME` column in a MySQL database. Saving a value of `9:00` was causing `8:00` to be saved in the database.

This problem did not occur on my dev environment (Windows), but did occur on two Linux machines we tried.

My code was the following:

```
preparedStatement.setObject(parameterIndex, localTime, JDBCType.TIME);
```

After investigating, I eventually found that the MySQL JDBC driver was using `java.sql.Time.valueOf(localTime)`, then using a `SimpleDateFormat` with its time zone set to the MySql server's `system_time_zone` system property (via `time_zone = 'SYSTEM'`), to print it as a string.

On the Linux machines, `system_time_zone` was `GMT`, and on the Windows machine, it was `GMT Standard Time`. (I am in the UK.)

So, the `LocalTime` `9:00` was converted to a `Time` of `9:00 Europe/London` (actually modelled internally as `1st January 1970 9:00 Europe/London`), and this was then written out using the `GMT` timezone, which is treated the same as `UTC`. Now, usually those two timezones have a zero offset from UTC in January, but the UK remained in daylight saving time for the whole year in 1969 and 1970. So an hour got subtracted.

### Question

What is the best way to write a `LocalTime` to a MySQL database, avoiding this kind of problem? I just want `9:00`, no time zone, no date, just the time of day. I don't want it to adjust for a difference in time zone, because it's just `9:00`, not on any particular day or place.

At the moment I'm just printing the `LocalTime` as a string, and sending that to the database, but I feel there should be a better way. Is there?

Comment: what happens if you save as string value `09:00`

Comment: When I use `preparedStatement.setObject(parameterIndex, "09:00:00");`, it saves as `9:00` in the database.

Comment: (That is the behaviour I want.)

Comment: I propose to have a function that returns string value for the local time using any formatter you use in Java

Comment: Ok, that's sort of what I'm doing; I'm calling a newly created function `TimeHelper.getTimeString(localTime)`. (Is that what you mean?) I just hoped there would be a way without converting to a string first...