# ResultSet.updateTime() results in a wrong value

Tags: java, mysql, sql

So, I have a local server of MySQL database on my machine and I'm trying to change a TIME column values in one of the database's tables, straight from a Java program.

What I'm trying to do is to fetch all the lines from a table called "Flights" where the source is "Amsterdam" into a ResultSet called `rs`, then update the time inside the result row's 2nd column to a value the user inputs, and then update the row inside the DB.

Those are the rows I want to update their 2'nd column TIME:

```
35  11:38:08    9W8915  Amsterdam   Cancelled   4
36  11:38:08    DL9644  Amsterdam   Cancelled   4
37  11:38:08    G35516  Amsterdam   Cancelled   4
38  11:38:08    GA9081  Amsterdam   Cancelled   4
39  11:38:08    KL1017  Amsterdam   Cancelled   4
40  11:38:08    MF9651  Amsterdam   Cancelled   4
113 11:38:08    9W8916  Amsterdam   On time 14:25   4
114 11:38:08    G35524  Amsterdam   On time 14:25   4
115 11:38:08    KL1019  Amsterdam   On time 14:25   4
116 11:38:08    MF9653  Amsterdam   On time 14:25   4
144 11:38:08    AA6505  Amsterdam   On time 14:35   5
145 11:38:08    BA435   Amsterdam   On time 14:35   5
279 11:38:08    G35530  Amsterdam   On time 16:05   4
280 11:38:08    KL1021  Amsterdam   On time 16:05   4
281 11:38:08    MF9929  Amsterdam   On time 16:05   4
```

The code:

```
System.out.println("Enter time: (HH:MM:SS)"); 
   SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
    try {
        Time tme = new Time(sdf.parse(in.nextLine()).getTime());
        System.out.println(tme);
        while(rs.next()) {  
            System.out.println(rs.getString(2));
            System.out.println("New Time: " + tme);
            rs.updateTime(2, tme);
            rs.updateRow();
        }
    }
```

The problem I'm facing is that the updated time is wrong.
I insert "22:22:22" and it seems that `tme` (Time object) recieves the correct time (because `System.out.println(tme)` prints "22:22:22") but the results inside the database are wrong.
That's the result AFTER executing the query with `tme`='22:22:22':

```
35  01:52:22    9W8915  Amsterdam   Cancelled   4
36  01:52:22    DL9644  Amsterdam   Cancelled   4
37  01:52:22    G35516  Amsterdam   Cancelled   4
38  01:52:22    GA9081  Amsterdam   Cancelled   4
39  01:52:22    KL1017  Amsterdam   Cancelled   4
40  01:52:22    MF9651  Amsterdam   Cancelled   4
113 01:52:22    9W8916  Amsterdam   On time 14:25   4
114 01:52:22    G35524  Amsterdam   On time 14:25   4
115 01:52:22    KL1019  Amsterdam   On time 14:25   4
116 01:52:22    MF9653  Amsterdam   On time 14:25   4
144 01:52:22    AA6505  Amsterdam   On time 14:35   5
145 01:52:22    BA435   Amsterdam   On time 14:35   5
279 01:52:22    G35530  Amsterdam   On time 16:05   4
280 01:52:22    KL1021  Amsterdam   On time 16:05   4
281 01:52:22    MF9929  Amsterdam   On time 16:05   4
```

The output from the console:

```
Enter time: (HH:MM:SS)
22:22:22
22:22:22
11:38:08
New Time: 22:22:22
11:38:08
New Time: 22:22:22
11:38:08
New Time: 22:22:22
11:38:08
New Time: 22:22:22
11:38:08
New Time: 22:22:22
11:38:08
New Time: 22:22:22
11:38:08
New Time: 22:22:22
11:38:08
New Time: 22:22:22
11:38:08
New Time: 22:22:22
11:38:08
New Time: 22:22:22
11:38:08
New Time: 22:22:22
11:38:08
New Time: 22:22:22
11:38:08
New Time: 22:22:22
11:38:08
New Time: 22:22:22
11:38:08
New Time: 22:22:22
```

As you can see, the time in the second column has been updated to "01:52:22" insted of "22:22:22".
I don't understand why the time in 2nd column has changed to 01:52:22 if `tme` contains 22:22:22.
Any ideas will be very appreciated!

Comment: Your example data is not consistent. What is the `11:38:08` value?

Comment: You can turn off the code-formatting of your plain text by adding he line `<!-- language: lang-none -->`

Comment: Seems a default timezone in the Java program differs from MySQL's one.
Here's similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53725799/saving-a-localtime-in-mysql-time-column

Comment: @BasilBourque Sorry for that. it's the result of input "08:08:08", so it's wrong too.

Comment: I suggest you fix your example data.

Answer (score 0):

## *java.time*

Using the modern *java.time* classes instead of these terrible legacy date-time classes may avoid the time zone problem you seem to encounter here.

Use a JDBC driver compliant with JDBC 4.2 or later. These later versions of JDBC require support for exchanging *java.time* objects with the database by calling `setObject`, `updateObject`, and `getObject`.

Your input strings comply with the standard ISO 8601 format. These standard formats are used by default in *java.time* for parsing/generating text. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

```
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.parse( "22:22:22" ) ;
myResultSet.updateObject( … , lt ) ;
```

Retrieval.

```
LocalTime lt = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalTime.class ) ;
```

### Example app

Here is an entire example app to demonstrate using a `LocalTime` object to update rows of a `TIME WITHOUT TIME ZONE` column.

This example uses the [*H2 Database Engine*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H2_(DBMS)). H2 is handy for such demos. Being written in Java, it can be installed in your demo app via Maven or similar tool.

First we establish a [`DataSource`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/javax/sql/DataSource.html) object, containing our database connection information. We configure an in-memory database using `mem`, as there is no need to persist this example database to storage.

Next we create a table of two columns, a primary key of type [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier), and a `TIME WITHOUT TIME ZONE` column for the time-of-day value. Then we write a couple of rows, with times `10:10:10` and `11:11:11`. We dump those rows to the console to verify. Then we update those rows, both getting the value `22:22:22`. Again, we dump those rows to verify.

```
// Establish an object implementing `DataSource` interface.
JdbcDataSource ds = new JdbcDataSource();
ds.setURL( "jdbc:h2:mem:localtime_example_db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1" );
// Set `DB_CLOSE_DELAY` to `-1` to keep in-memory database in existence after connection closes.
ds.setUser( "scott" );
ds.setPassword( "tiger" );

try (
        Connection conn = ds.getConnection() ;
)
{
    // Create database.
    String sql = "CREATE TABLE event_ ( \n" +
            "  pkey_ UUID NOT NULL DEFAULT RANDOM_UUID() PRIMARY KEY , \n" +
            "  when_ TIME WITHOUT TIME ZONE NOT NULL \n" +
            ");";
    try (
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement() ;
    )
    {
        stmt.execute( sql );
    }

    // Insert row.
    sql = "INSERT INTO event_ ( when_ ) \n";
    sql += "VALUES ( ? ) \n";
    sql += ";";
    try (
            PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement( sql , Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS ) ;
    )
    {

        // Insert row.
        LocalTime lt10 = LocalTime.parse( "10:10:10" );
        pstmt.setObject( 1 , lt10 );
        pstmt.executeUpdate();

        ResultSet rs = pstmt.getGeneratedKeys();
        System.out.println( "INFO - Reporting generated keys." );
        while ( rs.next() )
        {
            UUID uuid = rs.getObject( 1 , UUID.class );
            System.out.println( "generated keys: " + uuid );
        }

        // Insert another row.
        LocalTime lt11 = LocalTime.parse( "11:11:11" );
        pstmt.setObject( 1 , lt11 );
        pstmt.executeUpdate();
    }


    // Dump all rows.
    System.out.println( "INFO - Reporting all rows in table `event_`." );
    sql = "SELECT * FROM event_";
    try (
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement() ;
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( sql ) ;
    )
    {
        while ( rs.next() )
        {
            UUID pkey = rs.getObject( "pkey_" , UUID.class );
            LocalTime lt = rs.getObject( "when_" , LocalTime.class );
            System.out.println( "Event: " + pkey + " | " + lt );
        }
    }

    // Update rows.
    sql = "SELECT pkey_ , when_  FROM event_ ;";
    try (
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement(
                    ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY ,
                    ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE
            ) ;
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( sql ) ;
    )
    {
        LocalTime lt = LocalTime.parse( "22:22:22" );

        while ( rs.next() )
        {
            rs.updateObject( "when_" , lt );
            rs.updateRow();
        }
    }

    // Dump all rows.
    System.out.println( "INFO - Reporting all rows in table `event_`." );
    sql = "SELECT * FROM event_";
    try (
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement() ;
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( sql ) ;
    )
    {
        while ( rs.next() )
        {
            UUID pkey = rs.getObject( "pkey_" , UUID.class );
            LocalTime lt = rs.getObject( "when_" , LocalTime.class );
            System.out.println( "Event: " + pkey + " | " + lt );
        }
    }
}
catch ( SQLException e )
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

When run.

> INFO - Reporting generated keys.
>
> generated keys: 7554110f-a856-4945-9926-2d03ca819c93
>
> INFO - Reporting all rows in table `event_`.
>
> Event: 7554110f-a856-4945-9926-2d03ca819c93 | 10:10:10
>
> Event: c05a7be2-3c09-4e57-8861-c05161138199 | 11:11:11
>
> INFO - Reporting all rows in table `event_`.
>
> Event: 7554110f-a856-4945-9926-2d03ca819c93 | 22:22:22
>
> Event: c05a7be2-3c09-4e57-8861-c05161138199 | 22:22:22

Comment: Did you check it with MySQL JDBC driver?

Comment: Thank you for the attempt.
I did try to use LocalTime with updateObject, and the result is exactly the same ..

input "22:22:22" results in "01:52:22" and "08:08:08" results in "11:38:08".

so weired !

Comment: @AlonBarenboim I added source code for complete example app to demonstrate the effectiveness of using `LocalTime` class to update `TIME WITHOUT TIME ZONE` column using the H2 database.

Comment: @edwgiz No, I did not as I do not use MySQL. But my Answer uses plain code that should work with any JDBC driver claiming compliance with JDBC 4.2, 4.3, or later. Furthermore, I added source code for a complete demo using H2.